# How do I control the output of NJsonSchema for decimals

Tags: njsonschema

I have a C# object like so:

```
public class Foo {
    public decimal Number {get;set;}
}
```

And I create a json schema like so:

```
 var schema = await JsonSchema4.FromTypeAsync(typeof(Foo));
 var jsonSchema = schema.ToJson();
 return jsonSchema;


{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "title": "Foo",
  "type": "object",
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "properties": {
    "SomeNumber": {
      "type": "number",
      "format": "decimal"
    }
  }
}
```

How do I prevent the property **"format": "decimal"** from outputting in the resulting schema?

edit to add: Without modifying the class Foo -- I don't have access to it.

Comment: I think you can implement a spezialized version of JsonSchemaGenerator and override one of the generate methods to control this...

Comment: Or implement a schema processor, check the njs wiki for more info